# Ranking/Ladder System

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ranking

I'm trying to create a ranking/ladder system where the clans with the highest rank(1) should be at the top and the clan with the rank 2 next and so on. But I can't get this to work... I have tried different ways of this:

PHP:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clans ORDER BY rating DESC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $totalclans = $row['id']; 
}

$clans = 1;
$clansnumber = $totalclans;

while($clans <= $totalclans)
{
   $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clans WHERE id='$clansnumber'"); 
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
   {
      $name = $row['name'];
   }

   $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalmembers FROM members WHERE clan='$name'"); 
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
   {
      $totalmembers = $row['totalmembers'];
   }

   $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clans WHERE id='$clansnumber'");
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
   {
      echo "<div class='newestmemberusername'><a href='clan.php?clan=" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . ":</a></div>";
      echo "<table class='profileinfo' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";
      echo "<tr><td rowspan='4' style='border:none;'><div class='rankbox'>" . $row['rating'] . "</div></td></tr>";
      echo "<tr><td style='" . $firstrowleft . " width: 200px;'>Members:</td><td class='profileinfosecondrow' style='" . $firstrowright . "'>" . $totalmembers . "</td></tr>";
      echo "<tr><td style='" . $color2 . " width: 200px;'>Victories:</td><td class='profileinfosecondrow' style='" . $color2 . "'>" . $row['victories'] . "</td></tr>";
      echo "<tr><td style='" . $lastrowleft1 . " width: 200px;'>Losses:</td><td class='profileinfosecondrow' style='" . $lastrowright1 . "'>" . $row['losses'] . "</td></tr>";
      echo "</table>";

      $clans ++;
      $clansnumber --;
   }
}

echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='contentboxbodybottom'></div>";
}
```

Unfortunately it just shows all of the clans instead of ordering them after their rank. I have tried changing the id to rank and change it so that it first goes and check rank 1 then rank 2 and up to rank 10 (max rank), but then it still just shows all of the clans in an order which I don't want it to.

Comment: Your first `while` loop does nothing. You probably misplaced a `}`.

Answer (score 2):

can you explain the reason why are you using lot of while statements

try this

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clans ORDER BY rating DESC");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    $totalclans = $row['id'];  
                    $name = $row['name'];

            echo $id.'<br/>'.$name;


  }
```

Let me know if you face any issue and then try to elaborate what actually you trying to get from the database

Comment: If I would have 15 rep. I would have voted up your answer! Thanks a lot! It really helped me out! And all of those "while" were because of that I were connecting to different table so I could set variables for their "$row"-array. Once again thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clans WHERE id='$clansnumber' ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
```